# less or less_equal using set

Tags: c++, stl, set

We can pass a function as `<`(less) operator to STL data structures such as `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `priority_queue`, ...

Is there a problem if our function acts like `<=`(less_equal)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Effective STL -> Item 21. Always have comparison functions return false for equal
values.

Create a set where less_equal is the comparison type, then insert 10 into the set:

```
set<int, less_equal<int> > s; // s is sorted by "<="
s.insert(10); //insert the value 10
```

Now try inserting 10 again:

```
s.insert(10);
```

For this call to insert, the set has to figure out whether 10 is already present. We know
that it is. but the set is dumb as toast, so it has to check. To make it easier to
understand what happens when the set does this, we'll call the 10 that was initially
inserted 10A and the 10 that we're trying to insert 10B.The set runs through its internal data structures looking for the place to insert 10B. It ultimately has to check 10B to see if it's the same as 10A. The definition of "the same"
for associative containers is equivalence, so the set tests to see whether
10B is equivalent to 10A. When performing this test, it naturally uses the set's
comparison function. In this example, that's operator<=, because we specified
less_equal as the set's comparison function, and less_equal means operators. The set
thus checks to see whether this expression is true:

```
!(10A<= 10B)&&!(10B<= 10A) //test 10Aand 10B for equivalence
```

Well, 10A and 10B are both 10, so it's clearly true that 10A <= 10B. Equally clearly, 10B
<= 10A. The above expression thus simplifies to

```
!!(true)&&!(true)
```

and that simplifies to

```
false && false
```

which is simply false. That is, the set concludes that 10A and 10B are not equivalent,
hence not the same, and it thus goes about inserting 10B into the container alongside
10A. Technically, this action yields undefined behavior, but the nearly universal
outcome is that the set ends up with two copies of the value 10, and that means it's not
a set any longer. By using less_equal as our comparison type, we've corrupted the
container! Furthermore, any comparison function where equal values return true will
do the same thing. Equal values are, by definition, not equivalent!

Comment: The `set` becomes `multiset` or even worse?

Comment: @a-z - Unless your comparison functions always return false for equal values, you break all standard associative containers, regardless of whether they are allowed to store duplicates. Read the whole article from Scott Meyers, it should make it more clearer. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21852

Comment: @a-z: Worse. E.g. you can expect null pointer dereferences when the out-of-bound element would be the smallest or largest; it's also possible that the tree graph used internally suddenly stops being a tree and gets a cycle `10A->10B->10A->10B->` etc.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a problem.

Formally, the comparison function must define a *strict weak ordering*, and `<=` does not do that.

more specifically, the `<` is also used to determine equivalence (`x` and `y` are equivalent iff `!(x < y) && !(y < x)`). This does not hold true for `<=` (using that operator would have your set believe that objects are *never* equivalent)

Comment: Technically, you're describing equivalence rather than equality I believe.

Comment: @jalf: The standard certainly does make the distinction; the "weak" part of "strict weak ordering" means that two objects can be equivalent but not equal.

Comment: Not sure about the Standard, but there can be cases where `!(x < y) && !(y < x)` can be true, but `x == y` is false.

Comment: ok, I stand corrected. Thanks both of you :) And thanks for the edit

Comment: @Fraser: You're correct about `!(x<y) && !(y<x)` not necessarily implying equality for weak ordering. The standard doesn't care about "equality". It cares about "equivalence", which is tested via "two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be equivalent if for the comparison object `comp`, `comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) == false`."

Comment: @DavidHammen  Yes, that's my point.  Equivalence and equality are two subtly different things.  The original answer before modifications was describing equivalence but used the term "equality".

Comment: @DavidHammen: yeah, note that my answer was edited. I originally said "equality" instead of "equivalence", and as the commenters pointed out, that was incorrect. :)

Answer (score 6):

There is indeed a problem.

The comparison function should satisfy [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) which `<=` does not.